# OAuth Post Request Failing

Tags: shopify

I've got everything working up until Step 2 of the OAuth process where you request the actual token. I'm using a very simple jQuery Post request and constantly getting `Access Control Origin` errors. I've tried `contentType: 'application/json'` and everything else I know to try.

It's just not working and I'm not sure the problem. I've confirmed all the variables are set properly before the request. Simple post request...

```
var url = 'https://[STORENAMEVARIABLE].myshopify.com/admin/oauth/access_token';    
var data = JSON.stringify({ client_id: apiKey, client_secret: secret, code: code });

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        debugger;
    },
    error: function(data) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your OAuth requests from a server. This is the Javascript cross-domain security kicking in.

If you are using Rails you can use omniAuth and it'll take care of the whole OAuth dance for you. Otherwise you'll have to search around but most popular language have an OAuth library that you can just plug in.

Comment: I was wanting to avoid that because of the hassle but that's what I'll do.